# How to automatically delete all line breaks except before certain characters in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I have a document that is poorly formatted due to coming from a PDF, with extra line breaks inserted where they shouldn't be. I would like to delete all line breaks in the document except when a specified character begins the next line (in this case, the full-width space "　" and the opening quotation mark "「"). I can't work out how to do this despite reading up about Word's regex system. Can anyone offer any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a few steps:

1. Replace \r\n<full-width space "　"> (i.e., the character(s) used for CR and/or LF, followed by the character denoting full-width space) with an unusual string, found nowhere in the document, such as *ZQX*.
2. Replace \r\n<opening quotation mark "「"> (i.e., the character(s) used for CR and/or LF, followed by the character for opening quote) with another unusual string, found nowhere in the document, such as *ZYW*.
3. Remove *all* remaining \r\n (CR/LF).
4. Reverse step 1, i.e., replace *ZQX* with \r\n"　".
5. Reverse step 2, i.e., replace *ZYW* with \r\n"「".

Effectively, it saves the *valid* EOL characters, deletes those unwanted, then restores the valid ones.

You could make a macro to do this all with a key-press, if it needs to be done often.

*Caveat:* My experience with PDF files has been that EOL characters are added wherever needed to make the document fit the page, e.g., around images, breaking words and adding hyphenation, etc. The document produced by the above procedure likely will still need manual editing, though hopefully with less effort.

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is a more straightforward method.

1. Make sure all line breaks are the same.  Use Find and Replace to change all ^p to ^l or vice versa (^p = paragraph return & ^l = line break).  For this example we'll change all line breaks to paragraph breaks.
2. Find and replace all ^p " with ^l "
3. Find and replace all ^p with a single space.